# Selenium Click "Next" Doesn't Retrieve Next Page

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to simply click the "Next" button for the URL below, but the button doesn't seem to be recognized by selenium click function. Anyone able to figure this out? Much appreciated!

```
import pandas as pd
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="enforcement_next"]/a').click
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U have missed out a bracket in the last line. Change your last line to this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="enforcement_next"]/a').click()
```